# Get basename in url

Tags: php

I have url

`http://localhost:8888/cr/organization/test`

How i can get `organization` from URL?

I'm using

`basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` But it returns just `test`;

Any way for me to get `organization`?

Comment: What is the logic behind the parsing of the url?  Will "organization" always appear at that level and are you always going to be looking for "oganization"?

Comment: @Joseph_J no, `organization` is not always there. I need to send API request with slug1 - ( in my example it's organization ), and slug2 ( in my example is test ). So, let's say user type `organization2/test2` my variables will be different from my example. So i need somehow break that in array maybe ..

Comment: You need the folder the PHP file is in that is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pathinfo()` to obtain an array that breaks down the url into different components.  One of the components is the directory name.  Use `explode()` with the `/` as the delimiter and that will output an array containing all of the folders in the url.

Like so:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('http://localhost:8888/cr/organization2/test2');

$folders = explode('/', $path_parts['dirname']);

print_r($folders);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http:
    [1] => 
    [2] => localhost:8888
    [3] => cr
    [4] => organization
)
```

As I mentioned earlier `pathinfo()` provides an array with different components in it.  Another component is the basename.  That will provide you with the "test2" in your example.

```
echo $path_parts['basename']; //Outputs "test2"
```

Hopefully that will get you started to where you can apply some logic to get the desired results.